# Increase stack size c#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

My code generates characters 'L' into 2D-Array on random place, but I need program to check if there isn't 'L' already and if it is there, program should go through process of generation again. But there comes the problem, because Stackoverflowexception shows up. Does anybody have an idea how to change my code, or how to increase stack size?
(I have to mention, that I already tried increase stack size using Project Properties, but I don't have there Linker option. And also I'm new to programming, so I don't know how to use editbin or commands). Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
    public void Generate()
            {
                Fill();
                Fleet();
            }

     public void Fleet()
        {
            Ship2(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
            Ship3(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
            Ship3(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
            Ship4(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
            Ship5(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
        }

 public void Ship2(int x, int y, int r)
        {
            if (r == 0)
            {
                CreateShip(x, y);
                CreateShip(x, (y + 1));
            }

            if (r == 1)
            {
                CreateShip(x, y);
                CreateShip(x, (y + -1));
            }
            if (r == 2)
            {
                CreateShip(x, y);
                CreateShip((x-1), (y));
            }
            if (r == 3)
            {
                CreateShip(x, y);
                CreateShip((x+1), (y));
            }
        }

 public void CreateShip(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x <= 9 && y <= 9 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
            {
                if (Board[x, y] == 'L')
                {
                    Generate();
                }
                else
                {
                    Board[x, y] = 'L';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Generate();
            }

        }
```

This is the important part of code.

Comment: *Does anybody have an idea how to change my code* You need to post your code first.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us your code. I don't think increasing the stack size will help. I'm pretty sure you have some recursion with a buggy end-condition. This is the most common reason for this kind of exception.

Comment: show the algorithm. Then it might be possible that someone would have an idea how to change it

Comment: Code added to post

Comment: Like I said...when do you expect `CreateShip` to return _without_ calling `Generate` again? So your stack flows over with return addresses as the methods keep calling themselves without ever returning. Please use a debugger and you will see what I mean. It's hard to tell which part to change how as I don't fully understand the purpose of the methods.

Comment: I expect it to return without calling 'Generate', when number is between values, and L isnt there yet

Comment: @Koty97: But your calls to the method Generate don't change in their parameters, so if your first call fails you call the method again with the same input parameters. What different result than a fail you expect by using the same input again?

Comment: @ThomasVoß I thought that it will generate random number everytime

Comment: @Koty97: If Utility.R ceates random numbers then ok. But thats not in the shared code, so I thought maybe a small hint might save you some time in searching...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is: If Creation fails pass back a bool and try again from scratch.

```
public void Generate()
{
    Fill();
    while(!Fleet())
    {
        // I assume Fill clears your board again?!
        Fill();
    }
}

public bool Fleet()
{
    return Ship2(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4)) &&
           Ship3(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4)) &&
           Ship3(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4)) &&
           Ship4(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4)) &&
           Ship5(Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(1,9),Utility.R(4));
}

public bool Ship2(int x, int y, int r)
{
    if (r == 0)
    {
        return CreateShip(x, y) &&
               CreateShip(x, (y + 1));
    }

    if (r == 1)
    {
        return CreateShip(x, y) &&
               CreateShip(x, (y + -1));
    }

    if (r == 2)
    {
        return CreateShip(x, y) &&
               CreateShip((x-1), (y));
    }

    if (r == 3)
    {
        return CreateShip(x, y) &&
               CreateShip((x+1), (y));
    }

    return false;
}

public bool CreateShip(int x, int y)
{
    if (x <= 9 && y <= 9 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
    {
        if (Board[x, y] == 'L')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Board[x, y] = 'L';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note: This will still not work, if the input parameters to CreateShip never change. You will now not see any Exception but the Generate method will never finish.